# Editing dictionary (iterating in for function) in population function to auto populate views, likes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iteration

This is basically an iteration question, I think (has nothing to do with Django really), although I am Working on Tango with Django, exercises at the end of Chapter 5 (database).  Using Django 2.1 and Python 3.7.

Goal is to change a population script so that "likes" and "views" are added attributes of "categories."

Changed my models already, that is working fine (can see zero likes and views in admin, first link to code works).

Original code, works:
https://pastebin.com/Q09XJtvX

```
cats = {"Python": {"pages": python_pages},
        "Django": {"pages": django_pages},
        "Other Frameworks": {"pages": other_pages} }
```

and

```
def add_cat(name, views=0, likes=0):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    c.views=views
    c.likes=likes
    c.save()
    return c
```

Code as modified (lines 42-51 and 74 modified), not working:
https://pastebin.com/gqsAd8iS

```
cats = {
    {"Python": {"pages": python_pages},
     "views":128,
     "likes":64},
    {"Django": {"pages": django_pages},
     "views":64,
     "likes":32},
    {"Other Frameworks": {"pages": other_pages},
     "views":32,
     "likes":16}    }
```

and

```
def add_cat(name, views, likes):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    c.views=views
    c.likes=likes
    c.save()
    return c
```

If I keep curly brackets around the categories, I get the error "unhashable type: dict."  If I change them to square brackets, I get the error "list" object has no attribute "items"

*** Edit for further clarification:
If square brackets (list of dictionaries) is used, error is:

```
File "populate_rango.py", line 82 in <module> populate
File "populate_rango.py", line 54 in populate for cat
    for cat, cat_data in cats.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

The line (54) that's referring to is:

```
for cat, cat_data in cats.items():
    c = add_cat(cat)
    for p in cat_data["pages"]:
        add_page(c, p["title"], p["url"])
```

End edit. ***

Someone else, in a  previous version of Django seemed to just manually create each entry (i.e., similar question but not the answer I am seeking here: [Python/Django TangoWithDjango Models and Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699136/python-django-tangowithdjango-models-and-databases)).  To me, there should be a way to set the values of likes/visits and then pass them to the functions that make the categories.  But I can't seem to make that work.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 2 ***

As noted in comment, if I change cats.items(): to cats: in line 55, I get

```
not enough values to unpack (expected 2)
```

If I change the line to

```
for cat, views, likes, in cats:
```

Then I get:

```
File 'populate_rango.py', line 57, in 
    populate for p in cate_data["pages":
NameError: name 'cat_data' is not defined
```

End edit 2 ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the dict structure helped:

```
cats = [
    {"category": "Python",
     "pages": {"pages": python_pages},
     "views":128,
     "likes":64},
    {"category": "Django",
     "pages": {"pages": django_pages},
     "views":64,
     "likes":32},
    {"category": "Other Frameworks",
     "pages": {"pages": other_pages},
     "views":32,
     "likes":16}    ]
```

And changing the references in the function a bit:

```
for dicts in cats:
    cat = dicts["category"]
    catpages = dicts["pages"]
    views = dicts["views"]
    likes = dicts["likes"]
    c = add_cat(cat, catpages, views, likes)

    for pages in catpages:
        cat_data = catpages["pages"]
        for p in cat_data["pages"]:
            add_page(c, p["title"], p["url"])
```

That runs well up to line 71, when I get:

```
in populate 
    for p in catdata["pages"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.
```

(Which goes to making the pages, but the original question was about categories.  Still I'd like to fix the pages part.)

For the curious, the add_cat and add_page functions are:

```
def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title)[0]
    p.url=url
    p.views=views
    p.save()
    return p

def add_cat(cat, catpages, views, likes):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=cat)[0]
    c.views = views
    c.likes = likes
    c.save()
    return c
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what brackets you are changing. Currently you have a single set containing dicts, which isn't possible. You need a list of dicts:

```
cats = [
{"Python": {"pages": python_pages},
 "views":128,
 "likes":64},
  ...
]
```

**Edit**

As I said in the comments, you need a nested loop. The outer loop needs to iterate over the dicts, and the inner loop iterates over the items as before.

```
for category in cats:
    for cat, cat_data in category.items():
        c = add_cat(cat)
        for p in cat_data["pages"]:
            add_page(c, p["title"], p["url"])
```

Comment: Right but when I do that I get the error "list has no attribute items" at line 56.

Comment: Then you need to show that code and the full error. What is calling `items()`?

Comment: Error and relevant lines added above, edit marked with ***  Thanks.

Comment: So I don't understand why you are calling items at all. You should just do `for cat, cat_data in cats:`.

Comment: Now I get "Value error:: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"  error (for the same line of code).

Comment: You haven't thought at all about the structure of your data. The original code was iterating over *a single dict*, so `cat` was the key ("Python") and `cat_data` was the value (which itself was a dict, ie `{"pages": python_pages}`). But now you are iterating over a list of dicts. What will `cat` and `cat_data` be now? Perhaps you want a nested loop?

Comment: Right, so what I would like to do is pass cat:cat_data, views: # and likes:# to the for loop.  Like I was mentioning in Edit 2, it doesn't seem like i can just pass keys to the for loop and have it pick up and use the values.  And I tried some other syntax (for cat:cat_data, views, likes in cats:) but that returned an error.  It seems like the list is passing on three values but I am not really clear what they are (i.e., the cats or the keys within each cat).  I guess I am not sure how to get the info from the list of dicts to the right place.

Comment: Thank you for the additional edit.  However, the nested loop iterates through the list but still generates errors.  (LIne 59 "NameError: name views' is not defined.")  There needs to be a way to pass the info from the dictionaries to the modified add_cat function.